# Помогите пожалуйста с написанием простой программы на C++

Tags: c++

> Напишите функцию sumDigits, принимающую на вход целое число типа int от 1 до 9999 включительно и возвращающую одно целое число типа int — сумму его цифр в десятичной системе счисления.

К сожалению у меня ничего не выходит.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Спасибо редакторам за исправление

Comment: Подсказка: если разделить число на 10 и найти остаток от деления, то он и будет младшей цифрой числа

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Функция  откусывает по одной цифре с помощью остатка от деления на 10 и уменьшает число на одну цифру с помощью  деления, возвращает сумму цифр числа

```
   int sumDigits(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            sum += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return sum;
  }
```